# Command to Interrupt a hung thread running in a java process without code changes

Tags: java, multithreading, kill

I've a java process running and unfortunately **one thread inside the process is hung**.

I found the **Thread id** which was hung using [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html), however I was unable to find any references on how to interrupt this thread using the id?

Is it possible to **Interrupt/Stop a thread from console** (or basically outside the process) by using the processId and ThreadId?

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

PS : I don't want to kill the process as its just one thread which is hung. Also, neither do I want to make code changes to Stop/Interrupt the thread. I just want to kill it, so all its resources can be released.

Comment: As I understand it, threads run inside a process are part of the application. Unless you have code to handle/interrupt such thread, iam afraid you can only kill the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no baked-in way to kill a thread within the JVM, at least not a deliberately implemented one.

Having said that, if you have started your JVM with the appropriate parameters, so that you can start a remote JMX session to it, you can actually suspend the thread and inject a `RuntimeException` into it, which will almost surely terminate it (unless you are doing something gnarly with `RuntimeException`s in it).

- See [this blogpost](http://www.rhcedan.com/2010/06/22/killing-a-java-thread/).

P.S. You would never start your JVM in production allowing rogue JMX connections though, and if you're not in production, I'd guess that the above approach is not of much help to you.

Comment: hmm, yes. I came across this solution as well, but I don't have JMX connections enabled and I can't turn it on due to some restrictions. Is there a way I can enable JMX connections to happen only from a specific box and reject from any other boxes?